# Quantitative comparison of transportation cost per kilometer over the centuries?

Tags: communication, transportation

I am interested to see research on the development of transportation costs over the centuries. I realize the difficulty with researching this topic so I am interested in anything, which can enlighten me on the subject. The research will possibly be focused on types of transportation like over-land transportation, passenger transportation, transportation of letters and so on. The important thing is that the research enables a quantitative comparison over several hundred years. The research should show the impact of innovations and building of infrastructure so I can develop an understanding of the impact these these have had.

Comment: I voted to close as "not constructive" - the way this is asked the expected answer would be a link to a study. This adds no value to this site, you should be asking questions that can be answered here.

Comment: Could you narrow down your question to something that can be answered here?  Which centuries?  Which continents?  Which method of transport? ...  As it stands the question is too vast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim Blanning [The Pursuit of Glory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014016667X) has a whole chapter dedicated to this covering Europe between 1648 and 1815.  It covers costs, travel times, and road availability as well as water ways.

However, that is just a narrow part in time and local.

Comment: Is this then a quantitative comparison? I just want to be sure before buying the book.

Comment: Yes it does.  It has a lot of details.  You should be able to find the book in a book store first if you wanted to check but I can recommend the book to anyone interested in the time period as a really good source.